# How to draw angles without using coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles, angle

I tried to draw with Tikz two lines wich have (for example) a 15° or 75° angle and failed.

is there a function where I can give a length and an angle and LaTeX draws that line for me or do i have to like calculate the coordinates of the endpoint and have to use coordinates? (It doesn't necessarily have to be the Tikz package)

(and I also want to mark/labele the angles later)

Thank you very much

Comment: Ti*k*Z understands polar coordinates: `(angle:length)`.

Comment: As @campa said, TikZ understands polar coordinates (even with different radii: `(<angle>:<x radius> and <y radius>)`), it understands [relative coordinates](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.4). TikZ also ships with the [`angles`](https://tikz.dev/library-angle) library and the `angle` and the `right angle` pic which might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is confusing at first but here is a little key code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)-- (5,0);
    \draw (0,0)-- (15:5);
    \draw (1cm,0) arc (0:15:1cm) node[sloped, midway, above]{15};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)-- (5,0);
    \draw (0,0)-- (45:5);
    \draw (1cm,0) arc (0:45:1cm) node[ midway, right]{45};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)-- (5,0);
    \draw (0,0)-- (140:5);
    \draw[->] (2cm,0) arc (0:140:2cm) node[ midway, right]{140};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```